# Make a message box only pop up once in c#

Tags: c#

I have attached my code below. I am trying to get the message box to go away after one pop up until another action within the application triggers it.

```
using (VIModel vi = new VIModel())
{
    var VideoFiles = vi.VI_VIDEO_FILES.Where(a => a.SEGMENT_ID == segmentId);
    foreach (var vf in VideoFiles)
    {
        string location = vf.URL;
        location = location.Replace('/', '\\');

        string[] smain = location.Split('\\');
        string unamemain = smain.Last().ToString();


        string fileToCopySource = Path.Combine(inputDirectory, location);
        string fileToCopyDestination = Path.Combine(outputDirectory, unamemain);

        foreach (char c in fileToCopySource)
        {
            if (fileToCopySource.Contains(c))
            {
                // notify user that the inputDirectory isn't valid
                MessageBox.Show("FOO");
            }
        }
        if (!File.Exists(fileToCopySource))
        {
            // notify user that file doesn't exist
            MessageBox.Show("FOO");
        }

        //File.Copy(inputDirectory + location, outputDirectory + unamemain, true);
        File.Copy(fileToCopySource, fileToCopyDestination, true);
        lbConsole.Items.Add("Moved " + location + " from: " + inputDirectory + " to " + fileToCopyDestination);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is alerting multiple times -- once for every "alertable" condition it finds, i.e. input directory not valid.  What you need to do is record the fact that *anything* caused the condition that will need to be alerted, and then alert only once, outside of the loop:

```
bool needAlert = false;

foreach (char c in fileToCopySource)
{
    if (fileToCopySource.Contains(c))
    {
        needAlert = true;
        break; // no more looping needed.
    }
}

if(needAlert) MessageBox.Show("FOO"); // notify user that the inputDirectory isn't valid
```